# Is java bit shifting circular?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have this behavior using Java:

```
int b=16;
System.out.println(b<<30);
System.out.println(b<<31);
System.out.println(b<<32);
System.out.println(b<<33);
```

output:
0
0
16
32

Is java bit shift circular? IF not, why I get 0 when b<<30 and 16 when b<<32?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bit shifting is not circular; for bit-shifting `int`s, Java only uses the 5 least-significant bits, so that `(b << 0)` is equivalent to `(b << 32)` (is equivalent to `(b << 64)`, etc.).  You can simply take the bit-shifting amount and take the remainder when dividing by 32.

Something similar occurs for bit-shifting `long`s, where Java only uses the 6 least-significant bits, so that `(aLong << 0)` is equivalent to `(aLong << 64)`.

[Section 15.19 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) talks about this:

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, **only the five lowest-order bits** of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.
>
> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then **only the six lowest-order bits** of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x3f (0b111111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 63, inclusive.

(emphasis mine)

(You can't bit-shift `float`s or `double`s, and attempting to bit-shift a `short` or a `byte` would be subject the value to *unary numeric promotion* to an `int` anyway.)

You get `0` from `16 << 30`, because the 1-bit from `16`

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00010000
```

gets shifted off the end of the `int` and gets discarded.

```
// Discarded - Result-----------------------------
  (00000100)   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Comment: is it the same for right shift? only the 5 lowest-order bits of the right operand? Thanks!

Comment: That's correct.  The JLS Section I quoted refers to all shift operators: `<<`, `>>`, and `>>>`.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not circular shift. It's normal left-shift. It's just that, for `int` type left side operand, Java uses just 5 lower order bits of the right operand for shifting. This is as per [JLS §15.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five
>   lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
>   bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f
>   (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the
>   range 0 to 31, inclusive

So, for `16 << 32`, considering only 5 lower order bits of `32`, the expression is equivalent to:

```
16 << 32 & 0x1f
```

which is equal to 16.